# Mouse click to boolean

Tags: java, swing

Hello from novice java developer, I created a `MouseListener` and `MouseAdapter` in a thread to control mouse action for mouse pressed, released and drag action. Each action will do specific things but i could not assign each `MouseEvent e` from each action to a variable.

So, how can deal with this problem? I also wonder if the method parameter `MouseEvent e` is specific to each method?

Here is my code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        //@override deleted because i want to use e as a different action.
        public void mouseaction(MouseEvent e) {

            /* In here i want to control MouseEvent  e action
            (drag, pressed and released) and do specific things in with e event
            and if e changes state should be changed in code during while(true) */

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need separate thread just to add a mouse listener, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all this information from the `mouseEvent` by calling the method `getModifiersEx()`, for example:

```
int eventType = e.getModifiersEx();
if (eventType & MOUSE_DRAGGED > 0) {
    // Code to be executed when mouse is dragged 
}

if (eventType & MOUSE_PRESSED > 0) {
    // Code to be executed when mouse button is pressed
}
...
```

Note that the `eventType` is a bit field where multiple bits can be activated simultaneously.

Comment: Since you tell it at the end, you could have multiple modifiers, so the `else if` is not a good idea, multiple `if` is better to be sure to test every cases

Comment: @AxelH: Right, have modified my answer.

Comment: @FrankPuffer  int eventType = e.getModifiersEx(); returns 0 for every action

Comment: @ZekiÇelik: I corrected my mistake, you can check if the result of the binary `&` is greater than zero. (I was confused because in languages like C++ you can use an `int` as a boolean value while in Java this is not valid.)

Answer (score 1):

```
//@override deleted because i want to use e as a different action.
public void mouseaction(MouseEvent e)
```

You can't just make up method names. You need to implement the methods of the listener. You need to handle the mousePressed, mouseReleased methods separately. For the mouseDragged you need to implement the MouseMotionListener.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html). You can find sections on:

1. How to Implement a MouseListener
2. How to Implement a MouseMotionListener

which both contain working examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'll address this concern:

> I also wonder if the method parameter MouseEvent e is specific to each method?

Every time this method is invoked by Swing, a new Event is generated. Your `@Override` annotation makes no difference.

So when user clicks somewhere, a MouseEvent N°2556 is generated for it, and the method is invoked with that event as a parameter.

When user drags the mouse away, a MouseEvent N°2557 is generated, and the method is again invoked with this new event as a parameter.

---

More broadly: All those `MouseEvent`s will always be different instances. They are immutable, as well.

This means if you want to *persist* some information for your game loop to see, you need to store the relevant conditions in a field somewhere. And you won't be able to access it from an anonymous class because you won't have a handle to it. Here is a quick and dirty example (shameless reuse of @FrankPuffer's code):

```
public class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdpater {
    public boolean isMousePressed = false; // This info is persisted here
    public void mouseaction(MouseEvent e) { // This is only triggered upon user input
        int eventType = e.getModifiersEx();
        if (eventType & MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            isMousePressed = true;
        }
        if (eventType & MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED) {
            isMousePressed = false;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] argc){
    // Before the game loop:
    MyMouseAdapter myAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
    jpanel.addMouseListener(myAdapter);

    // In the game loop
    while(true) {
         if(myAdapter.isMousePressed) { // This info is available anytime now!
              // Do something
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: but if (eventType & MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) is int and compiler says it can not be converted.